# Fullscreen Exclusive: How to change the native resolution?

Tags: directx, fullscreen, dxgi

I can successfully control the native refresh-rate by specifying the refresh rate in `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC` which is passed to `CreateSwapChainForHwnd`.

I was expecting native resolution to change to that specified by the hight and width of the swapchain. However, I was not this lucky.

Moreover, the `CreateSwapChainForHwnd` suggests that you cant control the native resolution of the monitor since you can specify `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC` has a scaling parameter

```cpp
typedef enum DXGI_MODE_SCALING { 
  DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED  = 0,
  DXGI_MODE_SCALING_CENTERED     = 1,
  DXGI_MODE_SCALING_STRETCHED    = 2
} DXGI_MODE_SCALING;
```

But, video games are clearly trigging a mode change (temporary black screen) when they change resolution in fullscreen exclusive. So they must be able to change the native resolution. How are they doing this?

Also, I was wondering why `DXGI_MODE_SCALING_STRETCHED` only fills a sub-rectangle of screen (`DXGI_MODE_SCALING_CENTERED` centres on this sub-rectangle, and `DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED` aligns the swapchain's top right corner with the top-right of this sub-rectangle). This sub-rectangle also changes as the hight and width passed to `CreateSwapChainForHwnd` changes. Maybe it's that I'm really in Fullscreen Optimizations rather than Fullscreen Exclusive <strike>and this sub-rectangle is the same size of my window</strike>(changing the window size didn't affect the observed behaviour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH`
> Set this flag to enable an application to switch modes by calling IDXGISwapChain::ResizeTarget.
> When switching from windowed to full-screen mode, the display mode (or monitor resolution) will be changed to match the dimensions of the application window.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/ne-dxgi-dxgi_swap_chain_flag

Interestingly, the mode switch works correctly without the flag when changing refresh-rates but will not when changing resolutions

Comment: Keep in mind that for an LCD monitor, changing the resolution away from the 'native' means you are relying on the monitor's rescaling hardware to get the final result. In any case, you may also want to read through [this blog post series](https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swapchains/).

Comment: Thanks `DXGI_SCALING_ASPECT_RATIO_STRETCH` is probably want I want to use https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swap-chains-3/